# How can I configure phpcbf or phpcsfixer in Neovim using null-ls to indent code using 2 spaces?

Tags: php, neovim, formatter, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

I have read the documentation from both formatters and have tried different configurations using various coding styles with different arguments with no success. Here's a code snippet of how my configuration currently stands.

```
local present, null_ls = pcall(require, "null-ls")

if not present then
    return
end

local b = null_ls.builtins

local sources = {
    --php
    b.formatting.phpcbf.with({
        extra_args = { "--tab-width=2" },
    }),
    -- b.formatting.phpcsfixer.with {
    --   args = { "--no-interaction", "--quiet", "fix", "$FILENAME", "--using-cache=no" },
    -- },
    b.formatting.blade_formatter,
}

null_ls.setup({
    debug = true,
    sources = sources,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that in PHP CS Fixer you need to create config file, where you will be able to [configure whitespaces](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v3.48.0/doc/config.rst#configuring-whitespaces). Theres, simply pass 2 spaces with `setIndent` method.